# Select top n records from each category within same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, greatest-n-per-group

I've a purchase detail table that has `item id`, `purchase date`, and `item unit cost`.

I want to get an avg of an item purchase cost by selecting latest top 2 records from each item id.

```
Item id, purchase date, unitprice
1        3/1/2012        10
1        3/11/2012        8
2        3/1/2012        10
2        3/11/2012        10
1        2/1/2012        9
3        3/1/2012        10
3        3/11/2012        1
3        3/12/2012        13
```

I'm using sql server 2008 r2

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [Item id], [purchase date], unitprice, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Item id] ORDER BY [purchase date] DESC) rn
    FROM your_table
)
SELECT [Item id], [purchase date], unitprice
FROM CTE
WHERE rn < 3
```

I'm not sure how can you calc avg with latest two records, but sure you can add `GROUP BY` to the query if you need.

Maybe something like that:

```
-- CTE here --
SELECT [Item id], AVG(unitprice)
FROM CTE
WHERE rn < 3
GROUP BY [Item id]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT    [Item id]
            , [purchase date]
            , [unitprice]
            , [avg] = AVG([unitprice]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Item id])
            , [rnum] =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Item id] ORDER BY [purchase date] DESC)
    FROM    T
)
SELECT [Item id], [purchase date], [unitprice], [avg]
FROM CTE
WHERE rnum < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(unitprice) as price from yourtablename 
 where unitprice IN 
 (
    SELECT TOP 3 (unitprice) from yourtablename
     where itemid='1'
     ORDER BY unitprice Desc
 );
```

Get the itemid through dropdownlist or textbox.
Is't useful to you ?